# Subtract two dates with 'let' variable then average()?

Tags: linq, date, let, entity-functions

Attempting to subtract two dates from one another to figure out the number of days, then execute `.Average()` on the 'let' variable `avgConversion`.

I encounter the following error; LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
var averageConversion =
(
    from r in db.Registrations
    where
        (bu == "All" || r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu)) &&
        (region == "All" || r.Region.Equals(region)) &&
        (startDate == null || r.StartDate >= startDate) &&
        (endDate == null || r.EndDate <= endDate) &&
        !r.RegistrationStatus.Equals("Cancelled") &&
        !r.Status.Equals("Cancelled")
    let avgConversion = r.StartDate.Value.Subtract(r.RegistrationDate.Value).Days
    select avgConversion
).Average();
```

Thanks to Enigma, this is what ended up solving the problem.

```
var dates = (from r in db.Registrations
                                 where
                                      (bu == "All" || r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu)) &&
                                      (region == "All" || r.Region.Equals(region)) &&
                                      (startDate == null || r.StartDate >= startDate) &&
                                      (endDate == null || r.EndDate <= endDate) &&
                                      !r.RegistrationStatus.Equals("Cancelled") &&
                                      !r.Status.Equals("Cancelled")
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     r.RegistrationDate,
                                     r.StartDate
                                 }).ToList();

        var avgConversion = (from d in dates
                             let AvgConversion = d.StartDate.Value.Subtract(d.RegistrationDate.Value).Days
                             select AvgConversion).Average();
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Entity Framework translates a **subset** of all possible LINQ statements into SQL. If you use methods or functions that can't be translated the you get the "method cannot be translated into a store expression" error.

Instead you should pull your data into memory before doing the calculation so that you can run the full LINQ expression.

Like this:

```
var averageConversion =
(
    from r in db.Registrations
    where
        (bu == "All" || r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu)) &&
        (region == "All" || r.Region.Equals(region)) &&
        (startDate == null || r.StartDate >= startDate) &&
        (endDate == null || r.EndDate <= endDate) &&
        !r.RegistrationStatus.Equals("Cancelled") &&
        !r.Status.Equals("Cancelled")
    select new
    {
        r.StartDate,
        r.RegistrationDate
    }
)
    .ToArray()
    .Select(r => r.StartDate.Value.Subtract(r.RegistrationDate.Value).Days)
    .Average();
```

Comment: Thank you, I followed your logic but broke it out a bit more.